# Does anything else happen if I continue to throw candy on the ground?

Tags: candy-box-2

So I've gotten to a stage where whenever I throw candy on the ground, the same thing keeps happening. Is there anything else that could happen? Or should I just stop throwing candy on the ground?

This is what appears for me currently:

```
You threw 4 330 candies on the ground                         |                                     
________________________________________________________|     |                                     
|                                                             |                                     
|                                                             |                                     
|                                                             |                                     
|                                                             |                                     
| _                                                           |                                     
||_|                                                          |                                     
|---     -----------------------------------------------------|                                     
|          |                 ___              *nom*     ____  |                                     
|          |               \/   \/                    \/    \/|                                     
|          |       _____   /\___/\ _   ____(^_^)_     /\____/\|                                     
|          |     \/     \/   (_)  (_)\/    \/  (_)       (_)  |                                     
|          |     /\_____/\    |    | /\____/\   |   ___   |   |                                     
|          |     \/     \/    |    | \/    \/   | \/   \/ |   |                                     
|                /\_____/\    |    | /\____/\   | /\___/\ |   |                                     
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: By the way, I don't really want to know what exactly *will* happen (if something does happen), but maybe how many more candies I need to throw in order for something to happen

Comment: @Sterno Not exactly a duplicate. That's more about the earlier stages of throwing candy, whereas mine is about if anything will happen. It seems the answer provided on that page says "I don't know if he does something else.", so there's still something uncertain.

Comment: I feel like the other one should cover this too. "What happens if I throw candy?" and "what happens if I throw even more candy?" don't feel like they should be separate to me. What if after you get you answer, something different happens when continuing to throw *still more candy*? Collapsing these all makes sense to me. But I'm just one vote!

Comment: @Haidro Incomplete answers are not a reason to ask the question again.  We only need one question about throwing candy on the ground.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Alright sorry. The other question didn't actually appear in the list of similar questions so I had no idea it existed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've thrown roughly 11.3k candies on the ground, nothing happened besides the guy keeps *nom*ing. Don't waste your candy.